# Wordpress - Hueman Theme - How do I increase article content in home page?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using hueman theme. In the home page, its displaying around 10 article, how to increase the content size in each article.

I tried **Appearance >> Theme Option >> Blog >> Excerpt Length** but its not working!!!

I don't know where I gone wrong.

Comment: can you give link of these theme ? Cz you need to change it from the code.

Comment: [almayasabdam.com](http://almayasabdam.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is only one bulletproof way, change the length with wordpress filters like that:

```
function your_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 200;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'your_excerpt_length' );
```

where 200 - length of excerpt

Comment: If I replace `the_excerpt();` with `the_content()`. Its not working, which means `the_excerpt()` goes like a loop. I used your function but its of no use :(